# send myObject (serializzable) from Activity to Fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

Hy, 
My activity must receive an object using sockets ..

This activity has within fragment A and fragment B.

I wish that every time the activity receiving the object, send it to fragment A.

how can I do?

Comment: Don't you have an instance of the Fragments in your Activity? How are you creating and adding the Fragments? Show us some code.

Comment: use Bundle.putSerializable() in intent while starting activity A

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a perfect example of where an event bus would be very handy. Check out [Square's Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/). If you create an event bus and make it available to your activity and to your fragments (either via a static class or using dependency injection) you can send myObject via the bus without the need to serialize it.

Here's some example code. First I create a statically accessible global event bus in OttoBus.java. This is the bus on which we'll pass messages back and forth between the activity and the fragments. In the Activity I assume you'll have some kind of method that receives the data from the socket. The received data will be put in a SocketDataReceivedEvent object and sent on the bus. In your Fragment you register the fragment on the bus when the Fragment is started and unregister it when it's stopped (to avoid leaking). The Fragment must also have a method to handle the SocketDataReceivedEvent. This method can be named whatever you like as long as it's annotated with @Subscribe and takes a SocketDataReceivedEvent as it's only parameter.

```
---- OttoBus.java
import com.squareup.otto.Bus;

public class OttoBus {

    private static Bus bus = new Bus();

    public static void register(Object o) {
        bus.register(o);
    }

    public static void post(Object data) {
        bus.post(data);
    }

    public static void unregister(Object o) {
        bus.unregister(o);
    }
}


---- SocketDataReceivedEvent.java
public class SocketDataReceivedEvent {

    public Object data;

    public SocketDataReceivedEvent(Object data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}


---- YourActivty.java
public class YourActivity extends Activity {

    public void receiveSomethingOnSocket(Object theDataYouReceived) {
        OttoBus.send(new SocketDataReceivedEvent(theDataYouReceived));
    }
}


---- YourFragment.java
public class YourFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        OttoBus.register(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        OttoBus.unregister(this);
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onSocketData(final SocketDataReceivedEvent e) {
        // do something with e.data
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try this? If the answer was helpful please upvote. Thanks.